# How to wait some time asp c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I show an `alert`, wait time, and then close window in ASP.net and C#?

Code:

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('insert done ......')", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Wait", "window.setTimeout('', 1);", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);`

Comment: Did my answer help Majd?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
 "alert('insert done ......');window.setTimeout(window.close, 1000);", true);
```

Notice that it's `window.close` with no parenthesis, because `windows.setTimeout` expects a function, and the timeout is expressed in milliseconds, so it's 1000.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout